# Visual Studio build events

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I't trying to configure my solution in Visual Studio 2017 for cleanup after builds etc. I'm interested if there is a full list of commands/events for using in pre/post build events section. Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-use-build-events-in-msbuild-projects?view=vs-2017), there are PreBuild, PreLink, and PostBuild events.  These can be declared inline (which VS does):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>rd /s /q obj</PostBuildEvent>
<ItemGroup>
```

The docs demonstrate it split up into separate Commands and Messages, *but this didn't work for me in a C# project*.  I'm not sure if this is a C++ only feature.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    <Command>rd /s /q obj<Command>
    <Message>Cleanup intermediate output directory</Message>
  </PostBuildEvent>
<ItemGroup>
```

Additionally, you can augment the build pipeline by adding new MSBuild targets.  These can be configured to run before or after any specific target in the pipeline (there are many by default).  Documentation for that is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2017), especially the section titled *BeforeTargets and AfterTargets*.